# converted text into image using canvas display long text

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing, canvas, canvasjs

I have seen in a couple of cases of converting text into images but nobody mention that if a text is too long i-e more then 1000 words how can I display them in image with using a font size of 15px 
**my HTML code**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="the_text"></div>
<button id="show_img_btn">Convert to Image</button>
<div id="show_img_here"></div>
</body>
```

**my Script code**

```
window.onload=function(){
  $("#show_img_btn").on("click", function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 620;
    canvas.height = 80;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    var text = $("#the_text").text();
    ctx.fillText(text,10,50);
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src=canvas.toDataURL();
    $("#show_img_here").append(img);
    //$("body").append(canvas);
  });
};
```

My question is if I convert this image it will converted into one line help me how can i convert the whole text into image and set the height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy element and apply same style props, append to dom and get the with of it. based on that you can split the text. Helpful snippet given below.

// JS:

```
function getDimen(text) {
    var div = document.getElementById("dummy");
    div.innerHTML = text
    var h = (div.clientHeight + 1) + "px";
    var w = (div.clientWidth + 1) + "px"
    return({ h, w })
}
console.log(getDimen("some text hi a a s a a s as a s as a s as a s as a s"))
```

// HTML

```
<div id="dummy"></div>
```

// CSS:

```
#dummy {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
```